# How to enumerate list of registered users

Tags: flutter, connectycube

From reading the technical documentation for ConnectyCube, there does not appear to be an API to enumerate  registered users nor is there an API to test whether user is logged in. Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out, I can tag the different users and enumerate based on the TAG.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use diff APIs to retrieve users https://developers.connectycube.com/flutter/authentication-and-users?id=retrieve-users

Also, there is chat activity last request at API https://developers.connectycube.com/flutter/messaging?id=get-last-activity
which can be used to determine whether a user is online or offline

Also, you may provide a detailed explanation what you gonna build, so there will be more specific suggestion

Comment: I am building a call center application where the user can either schedule an appointment or call an available agent. The user can select from a list of agents to call. Thus, I need to be able to enumerate the list of agents and determine who is currently online.

Comment: The TWO APIs require IDS. The list of agents will be dynamic.